# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Tags: c#, datatable, sql-server-2012, datareader

I am trying to load a `dataTable` with a `dataReader` but for this simple process i am getting following error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   project.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My Code:

```
while (dtaRdr.Read())
{
   testVar = dtaRdr.GetValue(5).ToString(); //DataExists.
}
sqlTbl.Load(dtaRdr);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null Reference Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452613/null-reference-exception)

Comment: all columns are `not-nullable`, there is one which may have `""` strings but no nulls.

Comment: @marc_s sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `sqlTbl = new DataTable();` before starting your while loop?